# com-object from c# don't work on c++ project

Tags: c#, c++, com, c++-cli

I am trying to understand com-object concept

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.
`import` don't generate .tlh file

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

//#import "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb"
#import "COM_test.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
//#import "<Full Path>\COM_test.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);   //Initialize all COM Components

// <namespace>::<InterfaceName>
    COM_test::ICalculator calc;

    // CreateInstance parameters
    // e.g. CreateInstance (<namespace::CLSID_<ClassName>)
    HRESULT hRes = calc.CreateInstance(COM_test::Calculator);

    //COM_test::Calculator calc;
    //int a = calc.Sum(1,2);
    int a = 0;
    Console::WriteLine(a);
    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual studio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjvWH.jpg)

C# com:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COM_test
{
    [Guid("7FAFBE67-24F0-44F9-8C0C-10F795C4E838")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        int Sum(int a, int b);
    }

    [Guid("9A946209-4EF3-47BD-B4C7-8B1F2EFFCF53")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICalculator))]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Calculator : ICalculator
    {
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Общие сведения об этой сборке предоставляются следующим набором
// набора атрибутов. Измените значения этих атрибутов для изменения сведений,
// связанные со сборкой.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("COM_test")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("MagaEnterprise")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("COM_test")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2020")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Установка значения False для параметра ComVisible делает типы в этой сборке невидимыми
// для компонентов COM. Если необходимо обратиться к типу в этой сборке через
// COM, задайте атрибуту ComVisible значение TRUE для этого типа.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("COM_test.snk")]

// Следующий GUID служит для идентификации библиотеки типов, если этот проект будет видимым для COM
[assembly: Guid("2bacca61-7291-4b5d-aeab-16e2b2d6c93f")]

// Сведения о версии сборки состоят из указанных ниже четырех значений:
//
//      Основной номер версии
//      Дополнительный номер версии
//      Номер сборки
//      Редакция
//
// Можно задать все значения или принять номера сборки и редакции по умолчанию 
// используя "*", как показано ниже:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.0.0")]
```

Comment: There should be some error in build log. Can you open `COM_test.tlb` with OLE/COM Viewer or some similar tool?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic, tried on oleview, see no my object on list and can't open

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic, oleview throw error "DllRegisterServer in IVIEWERS.DLL failed"

Comment: Did you set project to register for COM interop or do it manually by yourself? The assembly option of [ComVisible(true)] says that all public classes are COM visible when the assembly is registered for COM interop. However, if the assembly is not registered for COM interop, it will not be true.  I always make a point of defining a public constructor for my classes that I want ComVisible just in case... You should be able to look in the registry at HKCR (using regedit) and find an entry for COM_test.Calculator. Also in HKCR, CLSID\9A946209-4EF3-47BD-B4C7-8B1F2EFFCF53

Comment: By design for an idispatch interface, use `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual` instead.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson, Project registered for COM interop and I have  COM_test object in register with this CLSID

Comment: Can you use VB script and run a simple script like: set obj = CreateObject("COM_test.Calculator")  You might have to run under 32-bit or 64-bit VBScript. Most times, the MS tools default to 32-bit when building projects. 32-bit VBScript EXE is at c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe (or cscript.exe).